# How to aggregate and group in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have lot of accounts with each of them having an employee assigned. I want to find the number of accounts of each employee. How do I do this task using aggregate of mongoose(mongodb). I am familiar with other functions of mongoose and able to achieve with following code

```
exports.accountsOfEachEmployee = function(req, res) {
  Account.find({active:true}).exec(function(err, accounts){
    if (err || !accounts) res.status(400).send({
        message: 'could not retrieve accounts from database'
      });
    var accountsOfEachEmployee = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
      if(accountsOfEachEmployee[order[i].employee]) {
        accountsOfEachEmployee[order[i].employee] = 1;
      } else {
        accountsOfEachEmployee[order[i].employee]++;
      }
    }
    res.json(accountsOfEachEmployee);
  }); 
};
```

Is using aggregate faster? How does grouping and aggregation work in mongoose(mongodb). Following is my schema of accounts

```
var AccountSchema = new Schema({
  active: {
    type : Boolean, 
    default: false
  },
  employee: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Employee'
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Aggregation is an faster than map reduce to get results in mongodb for simple queries. I am able to complete the above query with result and then group, count of mongodb. Following is the query I used later

```
Order.aggregate({$match: {active: true }}, 
  {$group: {_id:'$employee', numberOfOrders: {$sum:1}}}, function(err, orders) {
    res.json(orders);
});
```

Query is executed in 2 parts. First part is getting all the results which are active and then group them based on the value of employee along with getting a new field numberofOrders which is number of number of documents in each group formed when we grouped based on employee.

Comment: Looks like in Mongoose 5.x it wants an array. Your answer worked for me after I wrapped my aggregation objects in []. Thanks for the help.